# Why does this result in non-lazy fetching and N+1 select statements?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I expect to get only one sql query, but I run into the N+1 select trap. I don't really understand why. Here is is the problem in detail:

I have an entity "PlayerRef":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_ref")
public class PlayerRef {

  //constructor etc...

  @OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "playerRef")
  public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
  }

}
```

And a class Player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {

  //constructor etc...

  @OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
  @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="cr_player_ref_player", 
      joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="player_id", unique = true)           
      }
      ,inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="player_ref_id")
      }     
    )
  public PlayerRef getPlayerRef() {
    return this.playerRef;
  }
}
```

Now, in my program I use the following HQL query to get all playerRef entities:

```
Query playerRefQ = session.createQuery("select playerRef from PlayerRef playerRef ")
  .setReadOnly(true); 
playerRefQ.setParameter("sport", sport);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<PlayerRef> allPlayerRefs = playerRefQ.list();
```

This results in the N+1 Select statements:

1)

```
select
    playerref0_.id as id1_21_,
    playerref0_.... 
from
    player_ref playerref0_
```

N times)

```
select
    players0_.player_ref_id as player_r1_21_0_,
    players0_.player_id as player_i2_34_0_,
    player1_.id as id1_19_1_,
    player1_....,
    player1_1_.player_ref_id as player_r1_34_1_,
    ... 
from
    cr_player_ref_player players0_ 
inner join
    player player1_ 
        on players0_.player_id=player1_.id 
left outer join
    cr_player_ref_player player1_1_ 
        on player1_.id=player1_1_.player_id 
where
    players0_.player_ref_id=?
```

This is very unexpected, since I thought the collection is lazy loaded and the set of players of each playerRef should be a hibernate-proxy.

Anyone knows how I can really only load the playerRef entities without also loading the associated players? For my use case I need all playerRefs but not the associated players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here comes from the fact, that your underlying DB structure is in fact `many-to-many`. There is a pairing table `cr_player_ref_player`, and that means, that

- one `Player` can have many PlayerRef
- one `PlayerRef` can have many `Player`

See [Hibernate – Many-to-Many example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

because instead of this:

```
public PlayerRef getPlayerRef() {
    return this.playerRef;
}
```

there should be:

```
public Set<PlayerRef> getPlayerRefs() {
    return playerRef;
}
```

Confusion for `Hibernate` comes from this: `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "playerRef")`, mainly that the mapping will be found under the `"playerRef"`... where instead of expected `many-to-one` is much more complex and partially expressed `many-to-many`. And that's why we can see these wierd N+1...

Comment: thank-you for the explanation. I deliberately chose the join table approach, since I really want to keep the player table clean of a foreign key to the player_ref table. So the question is, can I keep my design and still get rid of the N+1 select statements?

Comment: As far as I know, this won't work. Why? Because Hibernate must know, how to construct the proxy of `players` set. Usually, it will know, that there should be some table, with a *join* column ... containing the current playerRef id... But now, the mapping says: there is not a column... there is a table... the pairing table. **Suggestion:** why won't you use the `@many-to-many` just on the `playerRef` side? for now, it must work. it will then definitely load only playerRef... and create correct proxy

Comment: I was confused. Unfortunately, this does *not* solve my issue. I still get the N extra select statements. :(

Comment: If that *(mapping the set as `many-to-many`)* does not help, then the issue would be inside of the app, which most likely, for some reasons, uses/iterates the collection. It could be some call inside override ala `toString()`... Because what I am saying is: **Once Hibernate has proper mapping of the `Set<Player>`, it will never loaded unless firstly touched**. So I suggest: inspect your code and all the usages of that collection. Maybe also, please, show your latest mapping ... could be something else...

Comment: I placed a new question concerning the many-to-many case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984188/why-do-i-get-n1-select-queries-when-lazy-loading-many-to-many-entities